# Endless loop in onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the following code:

**AppA**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.hasExtra("Key")) {
        Intent i1 = new Intent();
        i1.putExtra("Key", someValue);
        i1.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.AppB", "com.example.AppB.MainActivity"));
        startActivity(i1);
        finishAffinity();
    }
}
```

**AppB**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // The following code executes only on a new install of the app
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("Key", "1");
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.AppA", "com.example.AppA.MainActivity");
    starActivity(i);
    finishAffinity();
    
    // The following keeps executing in an endless loop
    Intent i1 = getIntent();
    if (i1.hasExtra("Key")) {
        long temp = i1.getLongExtra("Key", -1);
        recreate();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine (I got the value from AppA succesfully), except that the code commented above keeps executing in an endless loop. I tried to change `recreate()` to `startActivity(getIntent())` and `finish()`, but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying *the following code executes only on a new install of the app*, but do you have an actual check around it? Based on this code snippet for me it seems like you are just passing data back and forth between the two apps and that is why you see the "endless loop".

If that is not the case and you actually have some check before starting either of the app I would try to remove the key from the extras in app b after you read it out with `removeExtra("Key")`.

Comment: Yes, I have a check around it. I'm retrieving a value from AppA thats all.

Comment: Then remove the value from the intent before recreating the activity

Comment: I fixed using `startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)` followed by `finish()`. Which is better (safe), my fix or yours (`removeExtra()` followed by `recreate()`)?